# Entity Error 4.1 ObjectStateManager-an object with the same key already exists in the objectstatemanager

Tags: entity-framework

I simply load a page using the find() method which returns one record for display as a summary and my viewmodel also returns a list of what I call metrics so that the customer can visually identify the metrics they used for a project. If they did not use those metrics, then they can update the value to zero. Once they update the metrics, they click save to insert these metrics into the table. So what we find is that I originally had metrics pulled in from the Metrics table with a status ='Planned' for planned metrics. When they load these metrics into the page, these metrics will get updated with new values if necessary and then reinserted as new rows with the status='Actual'.

Original planned metric record - metricid = 1, metricstatus = 'Planned'
New Actual metircs record - no id prior to insert, metricstatus = 'Actual'

I get the following error during insert.

An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.  This is how I insert the record

```
IList<Metric> MetricList = new List<Metric>();

foreach (var projectMetric in ProjectMetrics){
    if (projectMetric.MetricTypeId != 0)
    {
        var metric = new Metric
        {
            Value = Int32.Parse(projectMetric.Value),
            MetricTypeId = projectMetric.MetricTypeId,
            ProjectId = project.ProjectId,
            MetricPhase = "Actual"

        };

        project.Metrics.Add(metric);

    }
}
```

This is how I save the change

```
this.Context.Projects.Attach(project);
this.Context.Entry(project).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

this.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public Project GetProjectByID(int? id)
        {
            Project ProjectQuery = Context.Projects.Find(id);

            return ProjectQuery;

        }
```

I actually send a json string back to the server which has all of my metrics. I deserialize my json string as follows:

```
List InsertableProjectMetrics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(metricsJSON);
```

I then call the InsertMetricMethod which loops through the Jason metric data.

```
 public void InsertProjectMetrics(List ProjectMetrics, int projectid, ref Project project, string Status)
        {
            //Insert Record: Insert New Record
            try
            {
                this.Context.Projects.Attach(project);

                foreach (var projectMetric in ProjectMetrics)
                {
                    if (projectMetric.MetricTypeId != 0)
                    {
                        var metric = new Metric
                        {
                            Value = Int32.Parse(projectMetric.Value),
                            MetricTypeId = projectMetric.MetricTypeId,
                            ProjectId = project.ProjectId,
                            MetricPhase = "Actual"
                        };

                        project.Metrics.Add(metric);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: How did you get `project`  ?  From DB or did you just create the raw entity?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below mention things when facing this error:

1. When inserting database table, having primary key of datatype, uniqueidentitifer, then set primary key column value in code behind as well. E.g. `RequestId = Guid.NewGuid();` Eventhough primary key is being populated within insert stored procedure using sql `function newid()`.
2. When updating a row in database table, do not set primary key column value in code behind. Instead, update the row wrt to primary key column value.

Answer (score 0):

The order when you add a new `metric` to `project.Metrics` and when you attach the `project` to the context is wrong.

You have many metrics with ID = 0 in the `Metrics` collection of your `project`. When you attach now this graph to the context EF puts the project and all children collections into `Unchanged` state. The exception complains that there is more than one instance with ID = 0.

To solve the problem you must call this line...

```
this.Context.Projects.Attach(project)
```

... **before** you start the foreach loop and add new metrics to the `Metrics` collection of the attached `project`. EF change detection will then automatically recognize them as new children and put them into `Added` state into the context. In `Added` state duplicate IDs are allowed (as long as your primary key is a database identity column).

Comment: I made this change and now I get the following: -->Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: @Nate: Do you still have the line there to set the state to `Modified`? If yes, remove the line and try again. (Or are there some scalar properties in `project` which you want to persist at the same time?) If you still have errors you should show the full code from retrieving/creating `project` up to `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Removing modified I get An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. I will update main question

Comment: The latest error says: "Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."   The inner exception is empty. It has no details.

Comment: @Nate: You seem to load the `project` from the database ("GetProjectByID"), right? In this case you don't need to call `Attach` at all, loading attaches anyway to the context (unless you disable that explicitely). So, try to remove the `Attach` line (although I have doubt that this is the reason for the error).

Comment: Do do get the exception on `SaveChanges` or somewhere else?

Comment: SOLVED: Wow. The problem was simple. My view page needed to have a reference to the projectid so I added a hidden field.  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Project.ProjectId)
That fixed it

Comment: These were probably two independent problems. The hidden field would not have solved your first error, I believe, the `Attach` were definitely at the wrong place.